# SQL select statement for reservation not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query which returns from my database the available vehicles based on the from and to dates a user inputs.

This is currently the date within my booking table.

```
Booking Table
booking_id     customer_id    reg_number    date_from    date_to    status
1              2              RH34 TJT      23-JAN-13    24-JAN-13  1
2              3              RJ54 FKF      26-JAN-13    26-JAN-13  1
```

Below is my query, it works if i put a date that is not equal to a date which is already in the booking table. For example if i put the `22-JAN-13` to `27-JAN-13` those two cars in the above table will be omitted from the results cause they are booked. However if I put in `23-JAN-13` to `24-JAN-13`, the car booked on this day will also be returned when it shouldn't be because its booked.

```
SELECT   *
FROM vehicles
INNER JOIN car_model ON vehicles.model_code = car_model.model_code
INNER JOIN manufacture ON car_model.manufacture_code = manufacture.manufacture_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking ON vehicles.reg_number = booking.reg_number
WHERE ((booking.date_from <= '23-JAN-13' OR booking.date_from >= '24-JAN-13')
        AND (booking.date_to <= '23-JAN-13' OR booking.date_to >= '24-JAN-13')
        AND booking.booking_status = 1);
```

Because i am using <= and >= the equals part will cause it to omit them as they are equal, or am i wrong?

Comment: Can you just change <= and >= to < and >?  What am I missing?

Comment: @sgeddes Hi, That seems to have worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT   *
FROM vehicles
INNER JOIN car_model ON vehicles.model_code = car_model.model_code
INNER JOIN manufacture ON car_model.manufacture_code = manufacture.manufacture_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking ON vehicles.reg_number = booking.reg_number
WHERE ((booking.date_from < '23-JAN-13' OR booking.date_from > '24-JAN-13')
        AND (booking.date_to < '23-JAN-13' OR booking.date_to > '24-JAN-13')
        AND booking.booking_status = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for vehicles that aren't booked on a given date, you should be looking to use a `NOT EXISTS` rather than joining to the `VEHICLES` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   vehicles v
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM   booking b
                   WHERE  b.reg_number = v.reg_number
                   AND    b.booking_status = 1
                   AND    ((b.date_to > to_date(:start_date,  'DD/MM/YYYY') AND b.date_from <= to_date(:start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) OR 
                           (b.date_from <= to_date(:end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND b.date_to > to_date(:end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) OR
                           (b.date_from <= to_date(:start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND b.date_to >= to_date(:end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) OR
                           (b.date_from >= to_date(:start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND b.date_to <= to_date(:end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')))
```